# A term for the person for which something is booked

Tags: terminology, programming

In the words of Phil Karlton: *There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things*:

[Context: Software, terminology for a database schema]

If I book something for someone else, is there a term for the person being the ... um, target of the booking?

For example, let’s say your secretary books a car on behalf of you. The secretary can be said to be the *organizer* of the booking (which is the term used by most calendar systems such as Microsoft Outlook when booking a meeting room), the car can be said to be the *resource*, but what is a term for the person the booking is intended for?

My own suggestions so far:

- Subject? (as in “to be the subject of a …“, but it’s ambiguous since it also typically means the topic to be discussed, as in the subject line of an e-mail, which could be confusing)
- Audience? (seems more like a group to me)
- Target [user]? (I seem to over-use the word target everywhere, but that may not be a valid argument)
- Owner? (would the one making use of the booking or the one who created the booking be considered the owner of the booking?)
- User (too vague in the given context)

You’d think the rich English language would even have a -ee word for something like this. But *bookee* sounds ... horrible. *Attendee* is not necessarily the primary user of the resource but could be an invited guest (as for an Outlook meeting, again).

Comment: In some contexts the person on whose behalf the booking is made would be a *client*. However this is not specific enough for me to propose it as an answer.

Comment: If it's a car, the *driver*, if it's a hotel room, the *guest*, if it's a meal, the *diner/customer/guest*, if it's a tool hire, the *user/worker/machinist/carpenter*, etc. *Responsible person* might also be accurate. Or as you suggest *target/user/subject*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a word for this, albeit an uncommon one: **sponsee**

As *Wiktionary* gives

> One who is *sponsored.*

*What expectations would you have of me if I were your sponsee?*

[Geraldine A. Miller, Learning the language of addiction counseling]

Another word that kind of applies here is **claimant**— if something is reserved for someone they become the claimant to that thing.

But I suppose these are somewhat awkward choices, and despite English being a rich language, it doesn't necessarily have a word for everything.

Comment: Apart from the awkwardness already noted within the answer, *sponsee* is problematic because it is meaningful only when there is a sponsor, and not all bookings are sponsored by a third party.